# What are the equivalents of encodeURL and decodeURL in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, url-encoding

What functions/modules should I use in order to have the same functionality like the client JavaScript functions: `encodeURL`/`Component` and `decodeURL`/`Component`? Is there a core module to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`encodeURI()`, `encodeURIComponent()`, `decodeURI()`, and `decodeURIComponent()`, are all standard ECMAScript functions - they should work fine in Node.js.

Comment: Ah! That was an easy one. Thanks! ;)